# Как ограничить область поиска в Яндекс Картах?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Как можно ограничить область поиска на Яндекс Картах? То есть, чтобы искал в отдельном прямоугольнике, заданным координатами, либо отдельно по городу? Я пробовал сделать так, эффекта ноль (пример взят из документации Яндекс.Карт)

```
myMap.setBounds([
                  /* Координаты юго-западного угла области просмотра
                     карты */
                  [56.366411 , 60.032195],
                  /* Координаты северо-восточного угла области
                       просмотра карты */
                  [56.584157, 60.463256]
                  ], {
                      // Включить проверку доступного
                      // диапазона масштабов (исключает
                      // возможность попасть в "серые тайлы")
                      checkZoomRange: true,
                      // Можно анимировать перемещение карты
                      duration: 500
                  }
                );
var myGeocoder = ymaps.geocode(
                      /* Строка с адресом, который нужно
                         геокодировать */
                      "Екатеринбург", {
                        /* Опции поиска:
                            - область поиска */
                        boundedBy: myMap.getBounds(),
                        // - искать только в этой области
                        strictBounds: true,
                        // - требуемое количество результатов
                        results: 1
                    });

                /* После того, как поиск вернул результат, вызывается
                   callback-функция */
                myGeocoder.then(function (res) {
                  /* Размещение полученной коллекции 
                     геообъектов на карте */
                  myMap.geoObjects.add(res.geoObjects);
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Все работает как описано в документации. Может у вас в заданном прямоугольнике нету искомого объекта. В этом случае ничего не будет найдено и не будет добавлено меток на карту.

Я попробовал найти объект, который явно присутствует на карте и он нашелся.

Вот, для примера, поиск улицы Ленина в некоторых городах (сначала думал искать площадь Ленина, но Челябинск оказался настолько суров что там такой площади нету).

```js
ymaps.ready(function() {
  var myMap, cityList, lookAtLenin;
  myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [56.70, 60.20],
    zoom: 10
  });
  cityList = new ymaps.control.ListBox({
    data: {
      content: 'Выбрать город'
    },
    items: [
      new ymaps.control.ListBoxItem({
        data: {
          content: 'Екатеринбург'
        },
        options: {
          selectOnClick: false
        }
      }),
      new ymaps.control.ListBoxItem({
        data: {
          content: 'Москва'
        },
        options: {
          selectOnClick: false
        }
      }),
      new ymaps.control.ListBoxItem({
        data: {
          content: 'Челябинск'
        },
        options: {
          selectOnClick: false
        }
      }),
    ]
  });
  cityList.get(0).events.add('click', function() {
    lookAtLenin('Екатеринбург');
  });
  cityList.get(1).events.add('click', function() {
    lookAtLenin('Москва');
  });
  cityList.get(2).events.add('click', function() {
    lookAtLenin('Челябинск');
  });
  myMap.controls.add(cityList, {
    floatIndex: 0
  });
  lookAtLenin = function(city) {
    var cityCenter = {
      'Екатеринбург': [56.79, 60.61],
      'Москва': [55.66, 37.64],
      'Челябинск': [55.15, 61.50]
    };
    myMap.setCenter(cityCenter[city], 9, {
      checkZoomRange: true,
      duration: 500
    }).then(function(res) {
      return ymaps.geocode('ул. Ленина', {
        boundedBy: myMap.getBounds(),
        strictBounds: true,
        results: 1
      });
    }).then(function(res) {
      myMap.geoObjects.add(res.geoObjects);
    });
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru"></script>
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 250px;"></div>
```

Comment: Тут конкретно ул. Ленина ищется в области, верно? А как сделать, чтобы все запросы из поисковой формы искали конкретно в заданной области?

Comment: Для этого нужно добавить пользовательскую [форму поиска](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/control.SearchControl-docpage/) с параметрами `boundedBy` и `strictBounds`

Answer (score 0):

У меня заработало, когда убрал из кода примера кусок:

```
, {
      // Включить проверку доступного
      // диапазона масштабов (исключает
      // возможность попасть в "серые тайлы")
      checkZoomRange: true,
      // Можно анимировать перемещение карты
      duration: 500
  }
```